# not able to establish database connection with php

Tags: php, mysql

firstly i have index.php in which code consists as below

```
<form action="connection.php" method="post">
<table>
    <thead><tr><td>Enter Item Details</td></tr></thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Item name :- </td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="30" name="item_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Item Desc :- </td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="150" name="item_desc"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add Item">
    </td></tr>
</table>

</form>
```

and my connection.php consists code as below

```
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="eatery";
$tbl_name="test_item";
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("Not able to connect to MySql");

echo "connected";
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("Not able to connect to eatery database");
```

I have installed wamp package to run apache server and my php code. Now while clicking on submit button of index.php, instead of database connection successful / fail message it shows inside code of connection.php. so what am i missing here?

Comment: it is displaying the exact content of connection.php ?

Comment: Make sure you didn't forget to write `<?php` at the beginning of **connection.php** script and `?>` at the end. Otherwise, server sees that as regular text/html.

Comment: I think the title needs to be adjusted. This is not a database issue.

Comment: @lagbox : yes it is displaying exact cotent

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 : yes i have included <?php ?>

Comment: is the php module loaded into apache ?

Comment: @PratikZinzuvadiya Hmm, so you have installed Wamp, successfully ran server (green icon in system tray), have put your content inside Wamp's `www` directory ... and it still doesn't work!?

Comment: ya after putting them in www directory its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Wrap that connection.php file in php tags:

```
<?php

// your php code

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

If this still isnt' working. Maybe you should make sure apache is using php. And you are serving your files through apache and not directly from the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass variable as variable not as string .

change this

```
  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die ....
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die...
```

to

```
 <?php
.....
.....
.....
 mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die ....
 mysql_select_db($db_name)or die ...
 ......
 ?>
```

and to debug the error and see the exact error use this instead of you error messages.

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: that should not matter

Comment: i changed variables but still same error. it displays content of page itself. also tried mysqli_connect

Comment: it displays content of page itself. ??? then you forget php tags :). in beginning use `<?php` and in the end of file use `?>` look edited answer

Answer (score 0):

In your *connection.php* try using this instead:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","eatery");
```

or you can just use:

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","eatery");
```

it should work! Cheers! :)